# Move mysql row to another table in the same database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a n00b when it comes to this stuff, apparently. I appreciate all the help this site has given me. So I am, once again, stuck on something. I want to copy over an entry from one table (appointments) to another table (deleted). I've gotten some help on deleting entries and that code will be in the main code, so here it is:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($transport, "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
foreach ($_POST['delete'] as $id) 
    {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
```

The delete code works like a charm. I also have code to update the fields:

```
$size = count($_POST['room_n']);
$i=0;
while ($i < $size)
{
    $room_n = mysqli_real_escape_string($transport, $_POST['room_n'][$i]);
    $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
    $sql = "UPDATE appointments SET room = '$room_n' WHERE id = $id";
    mysqli_query($transport, $sql) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($transport));

    ++$i;

}
```

Which also works 100%. I've tried to use the same type of while loop for the insertion of the deleted items to the delete table and it just gives me errors. I've also tried putting the insert code in front of `mysqli_stmt_execute` and I get it just doesn't post. So I am not sure what I can do. Thank you for the help again!

Comment: Why move it?  Why not add a column called "record_status" or something which could have the values "active", "deleted", etc?

Comment: Well, it's a transportation schedule. I don't want to have it overrun with mistakes. I want them to be able to delete it, but I also want to keep a record of cancelled appointments and errors for record keeping.

Comment: `SELECT a,b,c FROM transporation_schedule WHERE record_status !="deleted"`

Comment: I'm assuming I'd put that in a while loop, user1032531?

Comment: If you implement a status column, you will be keeping deleted records, you will just need to mark them as such, and exclude them from regular queries.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't get what you were saying lol. I can just have the mysqli_query pull out the ones that don't have that status ID checked... So yeah, I'm gonna do that lol. Thank you. I'll let you guys know how that works out. Just do an if statement to pull from the database, right?

Comment: No if statement required.  Just structure your query like I showed you so the deleted records are not returned.  Someone smarter than me should indicate whether you should index the column.

Comment: Would this be the right syntax?

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date = '".$date."' AND WHERE status = '" . $status . "' ORDER BY appttime";`

Answer (score 0):

You could use feature [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO `deleted` SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE id = $id
```

P.S. Do not forget to use transaction because you are performing an operation with two queries.

P.P.S. Better to add status field, like `id_deleted`

P.P.P.S. Do not use `mysql_` functions