# should delete status column in SQL table be indexed

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE status!="deleted"
```

Possible values for `status` are "active", "deleted", "pending", etc.

Should `status` be indexed?  Please explain why you feel it should or shouldn't.

EDIT.  t will hold a bunch of records.  Periodically, they will be deleted.  Instead of deleting them, I will just add a column called "status" indicated whether they are deleted or not.

Comment: It's not possible to answer on this question in general. It depends on the data, on how you use it, on what are requirements, etc.

Comment: The cost of an extra index is an additional `INSERT` time. So it depends...

Comment: Still not enough. How many deleted rows there will be in average. How you will select data.

Comment: How large is your *bunch*?  Are we talking about millions of records?

Comment: @zerkms.  Users will delete records.  Most users will only be able to delete one record at a time, but admin users will be able to select multiple records and change status "deleted" to "really_deleted"  I don't understand your question regarding "How you will select data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the queries with

```
WHERE status!="deleted"
```

predicate a B-Tree (and Hash) based index will be useless. Just because they do not optimize `!=` operator.

So having an index that covers `status` as its left most part will only be useful if:

1. You're using `=` comparison (or `IN (...)`)
2. The number of rows that to be selected is low (relatively to number of rows totally).

PS: if the 2 items above are the case - it worth having research on using `Hash` based index actually.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something very useful. I'll delete my answer ;-)

Comment: Yikes!  This is a big deal.  I don't understand B-Tree, however, I take it you do.  So, if the number of rows is high, and I only wish to display rows which are not deleted, should I abandon this strategy and maybe move them?  Note that I will have a LIMIT on the query which will limit to a fairly small number of rows. Don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: @user1032531: `LIMIT` will not change anything, it is still easier to full scan in this case.

Comment: I am having a difficult time coming up with an action plan. I thought this was a fairly common scenario.  I am not using `IN( )`, and the number of rows to be selected will be maybe 30% of the total rows.  Would an int index help (I wouldn't think so)?  Other thoughts?

Comment: @user1032531: help with what? What is the real problem you are solving?

Comment: Problem.  I have a bunch records which the user can delete some of them, but if deleted, they will not be actually deleted but just tagged as deleted.  I can either move them, or leave them in the same table but tag them as being deleted.  From a DB perspective, is one solution better than the other?  I actually made the recommendation to do the later at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688621/move-mysql-row-to-another-table-in-the-same-database.

Comment: @user1032531: so it's not a problem. Why do you need indexes?

Comment: It is not a problem with small data sets, but I don't know if it will be a problem with more data, and I would like to learn how to do it right.

Comment: @user1032531: it's really hard to solve the problems that don't exist. Try to avoid it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really going to have that many rows, it's probably worth having e.g. a small int status_id that links to a table with the actual statuses. This will save storage, be more efficient to index, and probably more efficient to search for as well, since it's an integer comparison rather than a character-by-character string comparison.